# How to sort a Multi Dimensional Array in Powershell

Tags: powershell, multidimensional-array, powershell-4.0

I have a script to cleanup a folder regularly. Every month there are 3-4 sub folders created; what i am trying to accomplish is keep a single folder per month and delete the rest on that folder on every server. I was successfull with the script, but ran into below block.

My array looks as below;

```
$Array = ((Filepath,Timestamp2),(Filepath,Timestamp3),(Filepath,Timestamp1),(Filepath,Timestamp4))
```

What i would like to do is, sort elements in array by timestamp; how to do that? Please let me know if any other questions regarding this.

Comment: Have you tried using a custom sort [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146635/custom-sorting-in-powershell)?

Comment: `$Array=$Array|sort {$_[1]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to convert the array of arrays into a list of custom objects and sort that list by the Timestamp property:

```
$array | ForEach-Object {
  New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
    Filepath  = $_[0]
    Timestamp = $_[1]
  }
} | Sort-Object Timestamp
```

Comment: That seems to answer my question , i can assign them back to array.