# PowerShell: Sort Drive Encryption Status for Custom Output

Tags: arrays, powershell, sorting

I'm trying to get the encryption status of all drives on a Windows system and sort that list in a custom formatted output.  I need this because the output is going to a Nagios server; it messes up the formatting of the standard output for `Get-BitLockerVolume` and is too long.

Here's what I have so far.  I'm trying to sort the output in such a manner that the system drive is listed first and gives the mount point (drive letter) along with the percentage.

```
[array]$DriveTypes = Get-BitLockerVolume | Sort-Object VolumeType | Select-Object VolumeType
[array]$DriveMounts = Get-BitLockerVolume | Sort-Object VolumeType | Select-Object MountPoint
[array]$WDEPercent = Get-BitLockerVolume | Sort-Object VolumeType | Select-Object EncryptionPercentage

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $DriveTypes.Count; $i++) {
    if ($DriveIndex -eq $DriveTypes.Count) {
        $TextDriveListing = $TextDriveListing + $DriveMounts.MountPoint+" ("+$DriveTypes.VolumeType+") at "+$WDEPercent.EncryptionPercentage+"%."
    }
    else {
        $TextDriveListing = $TextDriveListing + $DriveMounts.MountPoint+" ("+$DriveTypes.VolumeType+") at "+$WDEPercent.EncryptionPercentage+"%, "
    }
    if ($WDEPercent.EncryptionPercentage -lt $ReqValue) {
        $NoEncryptFlag = 1
    }
}
```

My desired output, for example, is this:

> C: (OperatingSystem) at 100%, D: (Data) at 0%.

What I actually end up with is this:

> C: D: (OperatingSystem Data) at 100 0%, C: D: (OperatingSystem Data) at 100 0%,

I did try something deriving from an answer to "[How to sort a Multi Dimensional Array in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812045/how-to-sort-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-powershell)" to test it out, commenting out my aforementioned `for` block and putting in:

```
$ListDrives | ForEach-Object {
  Get-BitLockerVolume @{
    MountPoint = $_[0]
    EncryptionPercentage = $_[1]
  }
} | Sort-Object VolumeType
Write-Host $ListDrives
```

That spit out this error:

> Cannot index into a null array.
>   At C:****************.ps1:142 char:3
>
> - Get-BitLockerVolume @{
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

What am I doing wrong?  Any suggestions?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Don't you want to use `$i` inside your `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $DriveTypes.Count; $i++) {
    if ($i -eq ($DriveTypes.Count - 1)) {
        $TextDriveListing = $TextDriveListing + $DriveMounts[$i].MountPoint+" ("+$DriveTypes[$i].VolumeType+") at "+$WDEPercent[$i].EncryptionPercentage+"%."
    }
    else {
        $TextDriveListing = $TextDriveListing + $DriveMounts[$i].MountPoint+" ("+$DriveTypes[$i].VolumeType+") at "+$WDEPercent[$i].EncryptionPercentage+"%, "
    }
    if ($WDEPercent[$i].EncryptionPercentage -lt $ReqValue) {
        $NoEncryptFlag = 1
    }
}
```

You weren't using the `$i` from your For Loop to access specific indexes in your collections (i've added [$i] to each of your collection variables to do so). You were also using a variable called `$DriveIndex` that was never populated and I think this needed to be comparing to `$i` also, however the logic was also one that would never be true because the For loop would end before it was so (so i've changed the logic to `($i -eq ($DriveTypes.Count - 1))`.

Here's a tidier version that I think also gets you the same result:

```
$TextDriveListing = ''
$Drives = Get-BitLockerVolume | Sort-Object VolumeType | Select VolumeType,MountPoint,EncryptionPercentage
$Drives | ForEach-Object { 

    $TextDriveListing += "$($_.MountPoint) ($($_.VolumeType)) at $($_.EncryptionPercentage)%,"
    If ($_.EncryptionPercentage -lt $ReqValue) { $NoEncryptFlag = 1 }

} -End { $TextDriveListing -Replace ',$','.' }
```

- Uses a single variable for the three properties you wanted to access, rather than putting them in to separate variables which was unnecessary.
- Uses a ForEach-Object loop to access each item (and their properties) in that collection via the special token `$_`.
- Uses a single double quoted string for output, with the object/properties accessed via the subexpression operator `$()`.
- Puts a comma on the end of each line, but then at the End of the ForEach, uses regex to replace the comma at the end of the line (regex: `$` token) with a full stop.

Both sets of code are untested, so may need tweaking.